# How to process key down state on LowLevelKeyboardProc with WH_KEYBOARD?

Tags: c++, winapi

How i could know if the key processed by the `LowLevelKeyboardProc` is from a `WM_KEYDOWN` or `WM_KEYUP` message when using the hook procedure `WH_KEYBOARD`?

`wParam` is returning the value of `vkCode` instead of `WM_KEYDOWN/UP`.

I'm using `WH_KEYBOARD` because I want to intercept only the keypress into the given thread as `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` only works globally.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    if (nCode < 0 || nCode != HC_ACTION)
        return CallNextHookEx(g->KeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* pKeyBoard = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

    // How to know if the msg is from a WM_KEYDOWN/KEYUP ?

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


int Main()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc{};
    HWND hWnd = nullptr;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = 0;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"test";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    hWnd = CreateWindowW(L"test", L"test",  WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 828, 492, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    g->KeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, LowLevelKeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), GetWindowThreadProcessId(g->hWnd, NULL));

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `WH_KEYBOARD` is a different hook from `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and passes different parameters. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/keyboardproc).

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks im reading the docs, so is possible to know if the msg is from a `WM_KEYDOWN/UP` using the `lParam`? asking cause I don't understand how to achieve this yet, maybe by checking the value of the flag `KF_UP`?

Comment: can i assume that the key is up by: `WORD keyFlags = HIWORD(lParam);`
`if ((pKeyBoard->vkCode == VK_INSERT) && (keyFlags & KF_UP))`?

Comment: you want use `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` or `WH_KEYBOARD` ? `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` for `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` but you use `WH_KEYBOARD`

Comment: in this case `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* pKeyBoard = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;` is wrong

Comment: It's explained in the documentation. Look at the table under `lParam`. It says that bit 31 tells you if it's a press or a release. It also links to [another page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input) that says you can use the `KF_UP` flag from the high word. Don't need to ask me. You can read it yourself.

Comment: `int Main()`? What programming language is this? It's neither C nor C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    if (nCode < 0 || nCode != HC_ACTION)
        return CallNextHookEx(g->KeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    
    WORD keyFlags = HIWORD(lParam);

    if ((wParam == VK_INSERT) && (keyFlags & KF_UP)) {
        // the key is up
    }

}
```